# Как расположить некоторые элементы td один под другим в одной строке?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть таблица с некоторыми строками:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Element1</td>
      <td>Element2</td>
      <td>Element3</td>
      <td>Element4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Сейчас выглядит как обычная строка, где каждый элемент идет в ряд один за другим. Мне нужно чтобы элементы **Element1 и Element2** были расположены один под другим, а элементы **Element3 и Element4** были расположены в ряд как обычно. Вот таким образом:

```
Element1
             Element3  Element4
Element2
```

Буду рад любым советам.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table>
  <tbody style="display: grid;">
    <tr>
      <td>Element1</td>
    </tr>
<tr style="margin-left: 50%;">
      <td>Element3</td>
      <td>Element4</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Element2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

И никаких лишних элементов. При желании можете перенести стили в отдельный блок или файл.

---

Используя только один `tr`:

```css
tr {
  display: grid;
}
td:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
  margin-left: 50%;
  grid-area: 2 !important;
}
td:first-child {
  grid-area: 1;
}
td:last-child {
  grid-area: 3;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Element1</td>
      <td>Element2</td>
      <td>Element3</td>
      <td>Element4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Референсы**:

- [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
- [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)
- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но можно ли сделать такую расстановку в одной строке, не используя столько tr ?

Comment: @ArnoDorian добавил ещё вариант, там чуть больше CSS, но зато используется только один `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr>
      <td>Element1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Element3</td>
      <td>Element4</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Element2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Костыль какой-то, а не ответ.

Comment: И в чем костыль при табличной верстке используемой автором? Вопрос не затрагивает адаптивную верстку на тех же флексах. Знаеш ответ качественнее, добавь не стесняйся!

Comment: Готово. (К тому же можно использовать пропорции `grid`-а по типу `grid-area` и т.п. при моём варианте)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но можно ли сделать такую расстановку в одной строке, не используя столько tr ?

Answer (score 0):

Совет первый: избавиться от табличной верстки в принципе. Если не имеете возможности, то:

Совет второй: волшебное свойство `display`, примененное к таблице и ее элементам, превратит их c точки зрения подхода к верстке в `div`-ы, что позволит вам расставить их как угодно.

Если все же таблицы вам нужны обязательно, то достаточно вспомнить атрибуты ячеек, придуманные в самой первой версии таблиц именно для такого случая (бордер у таблицы добавил для наглядности):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Element1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Element3</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Element4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Element2</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `избавиться от табличной верстки в принципе.` и чем же тогда заменить?

Comment: дивами. П.С. добавил свой вариант для таблицы.

Comment: Убрал `border`-ы, у вас всё правильно, но автор вроде бы хочет чтобы всё было в одном `tr` элементе.

Comment: @Инквизитор, нужно использовать свои элементы по назначению. Не говорится же, что это будет для верстки сайта.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, то вы спрашиваете "чем заменить", то вам не нравится то, чем предлагаю заменить. Когда разберетесь со своими внутренними противоречиями, напишите, пожалуйста, что в моем предложении не соответствует понятию "использовать свои элементы по назначению".

Comment: Человеку нужно таблица, вы говорите не пользуйтесь вообще таблицами, используйте дивы. В чем логика? Чем вам так не угодили таблицы? Вопрос не про верстку сайта в целом.

Comment: Задача была  в расположении элементов, а не в использовании именно таблицы, если вы не заметили.  Поэтому и дал первый совет, в этом и логика. Предположив, что таблицы все же обязательны, дал остальные советы. И, да, "Не говорится же, что это будет для верстки сайта" звучит, мягко говоря, как "автомобиль не для того, чтобы в нем ездить".

Answer (score 0):

Вторую и терью клетку объединить с помощью rowspan="2" Тоесть El3 Сделает row двойного размера.

```
   <tr>
    <td>Element1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Element3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Element4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Element2</td>
  </tr>
```